# В чем смысл поиска с барьером в бинарном дереве поиска?

Tags: c, структуры-данных

Про обычный поиск в бинарном дереве уже известно 
его псевдко-код понятен

```
Node search(x : Node, k : T):
   if x == null or k == x.key
      return x
   if k < x.key
      return search(x.left, k)
   else
      return search(x.right, k)
```

С идеей поиска с барьером в массиве (где больше не надо заботиться о границе массива и делается на одну проверку меньше) тоже знаком.
А вот как будет реализован и в чём смысл поиска с барьером в бинарном дереве ?

Comment: Барьер, это лимит по времени, или уже не надо. На пример в другом дереве параллельным потоком уже нашли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под бинарным деревом поиска с барьером обычно имеют в виду введение специального узла того же типа, что и обычные,  но со  специальным значением в поле данных. Этот узел используется вместо нулевых указателей - на него ссылаются все листья.

Перед поиском в `barrier.key` записывается искомое значение. Если после поиска найденный узел совпадает с `barrier` - поиск неудачен.

Таким образом достигается некоторая экономия - на каждом уровне рекурсии или на каждом обороте нерекурсивного цикла `while` можно избавиться от одного сравнения с `NULL`.

На мой взгляд, экономия копеечная.